# Flutter ios build fails. simulator builds also fail

Tags: flutter, dart, cocoapods

I've been working on an app for months now and using **Flutter**, but whenever I upgrade **Flutter**, it is a huge pain because I have to wrestle to try to get it to build again. Usually manually cleaning up **CocoaPods** and **pubspec.yaml** is enough, but this time it hasn't.

I've upgraded my **Flutter** version to **1.14.6** from **1.10.7**, nuked my **pods** and **pubspec.yaml**, nuked my installation of **Flutter**, my repository, and nothing worked.

Another weird thing about it is that I have the build running just fine with the same versions of flutter, dart, cocoapods, and ruby on the same branch on a different machine. Is there something cached somewhere that I am not cleaning up properly? When I try to build, it says it fails with errors, but unfortunately the log output doesn't actually show any errors, and only shows warnings. Here is a part of my log output:

```
8 warnings generated.
    /Users/hallo/Documents/dev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_sign_in-4.1.1/ios/Classes/FLTGoogleSignInPlugin.m:138:13: warning: unused variable 'sourceApplication' [-Wunused-variable]
      NSString *sourceApplication = options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey];
                ^
    /Users/hallo/Documents/dev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_sign_in-4.1.1/ios/Classes/FLTGoogleSignInPlugin.m:138:41: warning: 'UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey' is only available on iOS 9.0 or newer [-Wunguarded-availability]
      NSString *sourceApplication = options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey];
                                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/hallo/Documents/HalloMonoRepo/hallo/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/google_sign_in/google_sign_in-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIApplication.h:514:51: note: 'UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey' has been marked as being introduced in iOS 9.0 here, but the deployment target is iOS 8.0.0
    UIKIT_EXTERN UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey const UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey NS_SWIFT_NAME(sourceApplication) API_AVAILABLE(ios(9.0));   // value is an NSString containing the bundle ID of the originating application; non-nil if the originating application and this application share the same team identifier
                                                      ^
    /Users/hallo/Documents/dev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_sign_in-4.1.1/ios/Classes/FLTGoogleSignInPlugin.m:138:41: note: enclose 'UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey' in an @available check to silence this warning
      NSString *sourceApplication = options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey];
                                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 8.
```

Any help would be much appreciated as I have exhausted my ideas on what could be causing this error.

```
Pluto:hallo hallo$ flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v1.14.6, on Mac OS X 10.14.6 18G3020, locale en-US)
• Flutter version 1.14.6 at /Users/hallo/Documents/dev/flutter
• Framework revision fabeb2a16f (3 weeks ago), 2020-01-28 07:56:51 -0800
• Engine revision c4229bfbba
• Dart version 2.8.0 (build 2.8.0-dev.5.0 fc3af737c7)


[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
• Android SDK at /Users/hallo/Library/Android/sdk
• Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
• Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
• Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.0)
• Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
• Xcode 11.0, Build version 11A420a
• CocoaPods version 1.8.4

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.4)
• Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
• Flutter plugin version 39.0.1
• Dart plugin version 183.6270
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.42.1)
• VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
• Flutter extension version 3.8.1

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
• iPhone 8 • C40DD8DB-5860-4B94-8D20-372074B6E7BC • ios • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-13-0 (simulator)

• No issues found!`
```

Comment: Try building using the `-v` option to get verbose logs: `flutter run -v`

Comment: `** BUILD FAILED **


                     The following build commands failed:
                        PhaseScriptExecution Run\ Script
                        /Users/hallo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hkmupomiwzgwwybgvjflbqilwoeu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Script-BC68FF6F226F5DF100E3C5D3.sh
(1 failure)`

Comment: I got this with flutter run -v

Comment: What happens if you run it from inside Xcode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by changing a variety of things. When I did the flutter upgrade, it changed my project.pbxproj file by adding this line

`shellScript = "# Type a script or drag a script file from your workspace to insert its path.\n\"${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/run\"\n";`
 
which caused a lot of errors. I deleted this line, changed the build system in Xcode to default (it was legacy), and then in the embed frameworks in Xcode, I removed Flutter.framework.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running on Android Studio? VS Code? Could you post your `flutter doctor -v`?

Other than that, all those errors comes from [**google_sign_in**](https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in). Would recommend the following:

- Remove `google_sign_in` (and comment any screens using this dependency)
- Make sure you're following all the correct changes inside your [**iOS Folder**](https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in#ios-integration)
- Use a different library. `google_sign_in` may not be up to date with all the latest **Flutter** changes.

If your code runs without that library, it clearly shows an error with the latest upgrade changes.

Comment: I've added my flutter doctor. there are 10 other packages with similar warnings to the ones given for google_sign_in. But thats a good point, maybe the packages are out of date and don't have new versions. I did run pub upgrade and pod upgrade though.

Comment: try to remove the ones throwing errors until a successful run.

Comment: I found out there is a pod outdated command and this is its output, many of these line up nicely with the warnings I get.
`- abseil 0.20190808 -> (unused) (latest version 0.20190808.1)
- AgoraRtcEngine_iOS 2.9.1 -> 2.9.1 (latest version 2.9.3)
- BoringSSL-GRPC 0.0.3 -> 0.0.3 (latest version 0.0.5)
- FBSDKCoreKit 5.15.1 -> 5.15.1 (latest version 6.0.0)
- FBSDKLoginKit 5.15.1 -> 5.15.1 (latest version 6.0.0)
- Flutter 1.0.0 -> 1.0.0 (latest version 1.12.1307)
- gRPC-C++ 0.0.9 -> 0.0.9 (latest version 1.25.0)
- gRPC-Core 1.21.0 -> 1.21.0 (latest version 1.27.0)`

Comment: I've run pod update, but it still isn't fetching these new versions

Comment: does Flutter Channel Stable also works? Did you updated XCode lately?

Comment: I have the same issue with the stable channel, and I updated Xcode a month ago

Comment: did you tried with a real device? Did you try it with an Android device?

Comment: I think the dependency issue is a red herring. The build works on my laptop, and they both have the same dependencies installed. I've verified that the podfiles are the same

Comment: any chance to try it on a iPhone (non emulator)?

Comment: I can't get it to build, so I can't get it to run in xcode

Comment: today I deleted derived data, and have been messing with different installations of flutter

Comment: most extreme case is to create a project with the exact same package name/bundle name and copy your libs files. Not kidding, last week I could never run a Flutter project but yes with the exact same lib/ files on a new one. Could never fix the other one.

Comment: the error is in the compiling,linking, and signing portion

Comment: I managed to get an Xcode build going, these are the errors I got
`error: /Users/hallo/Documents/dev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_storage-3.1.1/ios/Classes/UserAgent.h: No such file or directory`

Comment: I fixed this problem by doing a pod deintegrate and pod install, but now I get this error. `/Users/hallo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hkmupomiwzgwwybgvjflbqilwoeu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Script-BC68FF6F226F5DF100E3C5D3.sh: line 3: /Users/hallo/Documents/HalloMonoRepo/hallo/ios/Pods/Fabric/run: No such file or directory`

Comment: Fabric? I know Google was killing that one... may a library still be with Fabric and be deprecated?

Answer (score 0):

Just run `flutter clean` on your project, it did the trick for me.